# SimpleDateFormat return string?

Tags: android

I have a method like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
  String currentDate =date.format(cal);
  Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra(TIMESTAMP,currentDate);
  startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

And I got app crashed at the line:

```
String currentDate =date.format(cal);
```

where I want to get the current date as `timestamp`for variable. I wonder if the value return from that line of code is not string ? Sorry for my dumb question but I am just a newbie. Thank you 
Edit : add logcat for more detail

```
11-10 22:42:00.495 9921-9921/com.example.admin.overtimenote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.admin.overtimenote, PID: 9921
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar
                                                                              at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:303)
                                                                              at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
                                                                              at com.example.admin.overtimenote.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

11-10 22:42:02.461 9921-9921/com.example.admin.overtimenote I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9921 SIG: 9

Comment: Could you share your logcat?

Comment: try with `String currentDate = date.format(cal.getTime());`

Comment: I added the logcat at my question

Answer (score 1):

try to use it as..

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            String currentDate =date.format(cal.getTime()); // here
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra(TIMESTAMP,currentDate);
            startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need only current time in milliseconds and it will convert it for you in required format.

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String currentDate = date.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent myIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(TIMESTAMP,currentDate);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```